# Fixing a bug in a tagged version (subversion)

Tags: svn, version-control, merge, tortoisesvn, branching-and-merging

We use SVN for revision control. Main development is done in *trunk* and branches are created where applicable for each user (when the intended changes are complex).

From time to time, tested versions get tagged (e.g. to */tags/v0.4*).

However, it may happen that a severe bug is fixed sometime in *trunk* (during other development).

Now I want to create a tag */tags/v0.41* which is the same as */tags/v0.4* but only with this single severe bug fixed (possible multiple severe bugs but surely not everything from *trunk*).

**How do I proceed with TortoiseSVN?**

I would suggest something like this:

1. Create a branch (`svn copy`) from */tags/v0.4* to */tags/v0.41*,
2. Merge the applicable changes from *trunk* to */tags/v0.41* and commit.

But is this a good idea at all?

**How do I do the merging from the specific *trunk* revisions (and nothing else) to */tags/v0.41*?** In fact, this would not be a tag any more but rather a branch which is not so good somehow...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The procedure you outlined is the right one.

The branch needs to be created to make sure that only the fix for the specific bug is committed to the new stable version (to *trunk*) and no additional (and potentially breaking) features are ported by mistake from the development version.

- Search the *trunk* for the commit that specifically fixes the bug you
  found,
- Create a patch from it and apply it to the */tags/v0.41* working copy
  (or merge just the required *trunk* revisions into the */tags/v0.41* 
  working copy).

NOTE: if there are multiple commits or there is no commit that just fixes the bug without touching anything else, you'll have to copy the relevant lines of code to the new tagged version by hand!

Comment: Hi, thanks! Two questions left: 1.) So I do not need branches, or do I? I checkout /tags/v0.4, apply the patch and check-in to /tags/v0.41? Or do I mix up sth? 2.) Is it really correct to do this with a patch rather than any kind of merge? I read in the manual that patch should be avoided since it breaks connection between files/revisions. But maybe this is not relevant here ...

Comment: @divB Yes, in fact it is more correct to merge, provided you've got one or more revisions that just fix the bug and nothing else (in other cases, you'll need to edit the files manually). You'll need to checkout /tags/v0.4, merge (or apply the patch, see above) ONLY THE REQUIRED REVISIONS from trunk and create a new /tags/v0.4.1 branch from the working copy. (The branch is required to separate the code of every version you release, so 1) if you need in the future to retrieve the code for that version again, you won't have to search through the log and 2) you don't mix up stable and alpha code).